# How to INSERT an array of uploaded filenames into a table and later display them?

Tags: php, arrays, database, forms, mysqli

I am working on a project where each item could have multiple images, I created a form that would accept the images and store them into an array. The problem is whenever I try inserting the images into a table row in the database it displays an error:

> "Array to string conversion"

How can I fix this? And also how do I fetch each images on another page from the same database table. Below is my code.

-Form code

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input required type="text" name="name">
    <input required type="text" name="location">
    <input required type="text" name="status">
    <select required name="category">
        <option>Category</option>
        <option value="construct">Construction</option>           
        <option value="promgt">Project Development</option>           
        <option value="archdesign">Architectural Designs</option>             
    </select>   
    <textarea required class="form-control" name="descrip" rows="5"></textarea>
    <input style="text-align:left" type="file" name="imgs[]" multiple>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" formaction="addaction.php">Add Project</button>
</form>
```

-Addaction.php code

```
<?php
$db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","dbpassword","dbname");
if(!empty($_FILES['imgs']['name'][0])){
    $imgs = $_FILES['imgs'];
    $uploaded = array();
    $failed = array();
    $allowed = array('jpg', 'png');
    foreach($imgs['name'] as $position => $img_name){

        $img_tmp = $imgs['tmp_name'][$position];
        $img_size = $imgs['size'][$position];
        $img_error = $imgs['error'][$position];

        $img_ext = explode('.',$img_name);
        $img_ext = strtolower(end($img_ext));

        if(in_array($img_ext, $allowed)) {

            if($img_error === 0){

                if($img_size <= 500000) {

                    $img_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $img_ext;
                    $img_destination = 'img/'.$img_name_new;

                    if(move_uploaded_file($img_tmp, $img_destination)){
                        $uploaded[$position] = $img_destination;
                    }else{
                        $failed[$position] = "[{$img_name}] failed to upload";
                    }
                }else{
                    $failed[$position] = "[{$img_name}] is too large";
                }
            }else{
                $failed[$position] = "[{$img_name}] error";
            }
        }else{
            $failed[$position] = "[{$img_name}] file extension";
        }
    }

    if(!empty($uploaded)){
        print_r($uploaded);
    }
    if(!empty($failed)){
        print_r($failed);
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $descrip = $_POST['descrip'];   
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $img_name_new = $_FILES['imgs']['name'];

    if ($db->connect_error){
        die ("Connection Failed: " . $db->connect_error);
    }

    $sql_u = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE name='$name'";
    $sql_e = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE category='$category'";
    $res_u = mysqli_query($db, $sql_u);
    $res_e = mysqli_query($db, $sql_e);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($res_u) && mysqli_num_rows($res_e) > 0) {
        echo "<div style='margin: 0 80px' class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'> Error. Item Already exists </div>";  
        header("refresh:3 url=add.php");
    }else{
        $sql_i = "INSERT INTO items (name, location, status, descrip, imgs, category) VALUES ('$name','$location','$status,'$descrip','$img_name_new','$category')";
    }
    if (mysqli_query($db, $sql_i)){
        echo "Project Added Successfully";
    }else{
        echo mysqli_error($db);
    }

    $db->close();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$img_name_new = $_FILES['imgs']['name']` is an array of one or more image names.

You will need to decide how you wish to store the array data as a string in your database.

Here are a couple of sensible options, but choosing the best one will be determined by how you are going to *using* this data once it is in the database.

1. `implode()` it -- `$img_name_new = implode(',', $_FILES['imgs']['name']);`
2. `json_encode()` it -- `$img_name_new = json_encode($_FILES['imgs']['name']);`

---

And here is my **good deed for the year**...

Form Script:

```
<?php
if (!$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "db")) {  // declare and check for a falsey value
    echo "Connection Failure"; // $db->connect_error <-- never show actual error details to public
} else {
    if ($result = $db->query("SELECT name FROM items")) {
        for ($rows = []; $row = $result->fetch_row(); $rows[] = $row);
        $result->free();
        ?>
        <script>
            function checkName() {
                var names = '<?php echo json_encode($rows); ?>';
                var value = document.forms['project']['name'].value;
                if (names.indexOf(value) !== -1) {  // might not work on some old browsers
                    alert(value + ' is not a unique name.  Please choose another.');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    <form name="project" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkName()">
        Name: <input required type="text" name="name"><br>
        Location: <input required type="text" name="location"><br>
        Status: <input required type="text" name="status"><br>
        Category: <select required name="category">
        <?php
        if ($result = $db->query("SELECT category, category_alias FROM categories")) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<option value=\"{$row['category']}\">{$row['category_alias']}</option>";
            }
        }
        ?>
        </select><br>
        <textarea required class="form-control" name="descrip" rows="5"></textarea><br>
        <input style="text-align:left" type="file" name="imgs[]" multiple><br>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" formaction="addaction.php">Add Project</button>
    </form>
    <?php
}
```

*notice that I have made a separate `category` table for validation.

Submission Handling Script: (addaction.php)

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['location'], $_POST['status'], $_POST['descrip'], $_POST['category'], $_FILES['imgs']['name'][0])) {
    $paths = [];
    if (!empty($_FILES['imgs']['name'][0])) {
        $imgs = $_FILES['imgs'];
        $allowed = array('jpg', 'png');
        foreach($imgs['name'] as $position => $img_name){
            $img_tmp = $imgs['tmp_name'][$position];
            $img_size = $imgs['size'][$position];
            $img_error = $imgs['error'][$position];
            $img_ext = strtolower(pathinfo($img_name)['extension']);
            if (!in_array($img_ext, $allowed)) {
                $errors[] = "File extension is not in whitelist for $img_name ($position)";
            } elseif ($img_error) {
                $errors[] = "Image error for $img_name ($position): $image_error";
            } elseif ($img_size > 500000) {
                $errors[] = "Image $image_name ($position) is too large";
            } else {
                $img_destination = 'img/' . uniqid('', true) . ".$img_ext";
                if (!move_uploaded_file($img_tmp, $img_destination)) {
                    $errors[] = "Failed to move $img_name ($position) to new directory";
                } else {
                    $paths[] = $img_destination;
                }
             }
         }
    }

    if (!empty($errors)) {
        echo '<ul><li>' , implode('</li><li>', $errors) , '</li></ul>';
    } elseif (!$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "db")) {  // declare and check for a falsey value
        echo "Connection Failure"; // $db->connect_error <-- never show actual error details to public
    } elseif (!$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM categories WHERE category = ?")) {
        echo "Prepare Syntax Error"; // $db->error; <-- never show actual error details to public
    } elseif (!$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['category']) || !$stmt->execute() || !$stmt->bind_result($found) || !$stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "Category Statement Error"; // $stmt->error; <-- never show actual error details to public
    } elseif (!$found) {
        echo "Category Not Found - Project Not Saved";
    } else {
        $stmt->close();
        $cs_paths = (string)implode(',', $paths);
        // Set the `name` column in `items` to UNIQUE so that you cannot receive duplicate names in database table
        if (!$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO items (name, location, status, category, descrip, imgs) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)")) {
            echo "Error @ prepare"; // $db->error;  // don't show to public
        } elseif (!$stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $_POST['name'], $_POST['location'], $_POST['status'], $_POST['category'], $_POST['descrip'], $cs_paths)) {
            echo "Error @ bind";  // $stmt->error;  // don't show to public
        } elseif (!$stmt->execute()) {
            if ($stmt->errno == 1062) {
                echo "Duplicate name submitted, please go back to the form and change the project name to be unique";
            } else {
                echo "Error @ execute" , $stmt->error;  // $stmt->error;  // don't show to public
            }
        } else {
            echo "Project Added Successfully"; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Taufiq I have updated my answer to be super generous.

Comment: Don't merely copy-paste.  Please read every line of code and try to understand what it does and why I've done it.  If something doesn't make sense to you, please refer to the php manual for function details.  After researching, if you still don't understand, you are welcome to ask me to explain.  It is a lot to take in, but immersing yourself in new/different coding styles, you will experience massive technical growth.  We are all here to help each other -- I hope that you will help others when you are ready/able.

Comment: When you want to access the comma-separated filename from your database table, you will only need to `explode()` the values on each `,`.

Comment: This is great I finally got it working. I'm stuck though, how do I explode  the array and get each image. I inserted into the database using the implode function

Comment: Show me your attempt, I'll have a look.

Comment: I just want to display each image name then from there I would be able to manipulate the data and use it. `<?php 
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM projects";
$project = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
?>
<?php
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($project)){
?>     
<?php
$imgs = explode(',',$row["imgs"]);
echo $imgs "<br>";
?>
<?php
}
?>`

Comment: After exploding to `$imgs`, you will need to write another loop.  `foreach ($imgs as $img) { echo $img; }`

Comment: Ohhh, It worked. How do i get individual image? I am trying to display the images in an image gallery

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking me.  Do you mean how to write an `img` tag with a `src` attribute?  Have a Google and let me know how you go.

Comment: Not how to write an img tag. After using the foreach loop, I was able to echo all images. What I want is how to get each image so I can use to create the image gallery. Is there a better way I can communicate with you? I am from Nigeria

Comment: We can open up a chat window or you could show me a drawing/screenshot of what you are trying to achieve.  Honestly, I am helping someone else right now and I am not sure that your question is a simple one. (it seems like a brand new task)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to chat. I'm suggesting WhatsApp if it's fine with you. I really need help with this project, it's a school project

Comment: Then it is really important that I not help you too much -- that would give your teacher an incorrect measure of your ability.  After you have some code for me to review, drop me a https://3v4l.org/ demo link and I'll look over your code. Do the work my friend, I'll help after you have had a good go at it.

Comment: Well I figured it out and the whole project now works well. Thanks a lot

Comment: Congrats.  Spoken like a real developer.  Great work.